# Incorrect Syntax in code to filter subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I am trying to use an `AfterUpdate` event to filter a subform based on the selection in a combobox.

For some reason I keep getting a error: `Run-time error '3075': Syntax error in string in query expression 'VendorID = 1".`

The code is:

```
Private Sub Combo104_AfterUpdate()

Me.ProductSelectionSubform.Form.Filter = "VendorID = " & Me.Combo104.Value & "'"
Me.ProductSelectionSubform.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Its nice and simple, but it keeps throwing that error. If I add a `'` in `= '"` I get a a mismatch error.

Where am I messing up with this?

Comment: Did you try: `Me.ProductSelectionSubform.Form.Filter = "VendorID = " & Me.Combo104.Value`

Comment: That did, For once, I actually OVER complicated something. Sometimes all it needs is a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Since criteria field is a number type, no delimiters are needed - remove the apostrophe.

If field were text type, then the apostrophe would need a mate.

Use # delimiter for date/time field parameters.

Value is default property for data controls. Can save yourself some typing and omit it.